# screen with urxvt keybindings

Tags: gnu-screen, rxvt

I promise I've been searching thoroughly for an answer...

So, my goal is to emulate the standard urxvt "tabbed" behaviour with screen keybinds, i.e. map three keybinds and that's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> (prev), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> (next), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>down</kbd> (new(?)).

Now I've found the keybinds for left and right on several comments like [here](https://serverfault.com/a/318534) and  [here.](http://www.kuro5hin.org/comments/2004/3/9/16838/14935/175#175)

So it seems that `Oc` and `Od` equal "right arrow" and "left arrow" keys.

But I can't figure out where to look up the rest of the keybinds. I tried getting the keys via  [xev](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) and the output looks like

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0xac, subw 0x0, time 50192748, (212,-106), root:(213,319),
    state 0x4, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES
```

I guess the answer is somewhere in this output, but I can't find the appropriate value (octal? hex? or is it something different for urxvt entirely?).

Maybe someone can point me to the right solution?

`.screenrc` should look like

```
bindkey "^[Oc" next
bindkey "^[Od" prev
bindkey "^[DOWN" new
```

thank you and cheers 
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `xev`, if you use `cat -v`, you can find the characters sent by urxvt:

```
bindkey "^[Oc" next
bindkey "^[Od" prev
bindkey "^[Ob" new
```

`xev` shows X events, which are interpreted by the terminal emulator, and sent to your application (such as `screen`) as characters.  To set up bindings for `screen`, you have to work with those characters rather than the original X events.

Further reading:

- [How can I see what my keyboard sends?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#visible_keys) (ncurses FAQ)
- [How can I use shift- or control-modifiers?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#modified_keys) (ncurses FAQ)